# How to cancel the execution of a method?

Tags: c#

Consider i execute a method 'Method1' in C#.
Once the execution goes into the method i check few condition and if any of them is false, then the execution of  Method1 should be stopped. how can i do this, i.e can the execution of a method when certain conditions are met.?

but my code is something like this,

```
int Method1()
{
    switch(exp)
    {
        case 1:
        if(condition)
            //do the following. **
        else
            //Stop executing the method.**
        break;
        case2:
        ...
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you want to exit the program after you stop executing? or do you want to return to the calling method?

Answer (score 38, accepted):

Use the `return` statement.

```
if(!condition1) return;
if(!condition2) return;

// body...
```

Comment: Or you can say `if(!condition1 || !condition2) return;`

Answer (score 15):

I think this is what you are looking for.

```
if( myCondition || !myOtherCondition )
    return;
```

Hope it answered your question.

### Edit:

If you want to exit the method due to an error you can throw an exception like this:

```
throw new Exception( "My error message" );
```

If you want to return with a value, you should return like before with the value you want:

```
return 0;
```

If it is the Exception you need you can catch it with a try catch in the method calling your method, for instance:

```
void method1()
{
    try
    {
        method2( 1 );
    }
    catch( MyCustomException e )
    {
        // put error handling here
    }

 }

int method2( int val )
{
    if( val == 1 )
       throw new MyCustomException( "my exception" );

    return val;
}
```

MyCustomException inherits from the Exception class.

Comment: "== true"? how about ( (myCondition == true) == true )?

Answer (score 3):

Are you talking about multi threading?

or something like

```
int method1(int inputvalue)
{
   /* checking conditions */
   if(inputvalue < 20)
   {
      //This moves the execution back to the calling function
      return 0; 
   }
   if(inputvalue > 100)
   {
      //This 'throws' an error, which could stop execution in the calling function.
      throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException(); 
   }
   //otherwise, continue executing in method1

   /* ... do stuff ... */

   return returnValue;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

There are a few ways to do that. You can use `return` or `throw` depending if you consider it an error or not.

Answer (score 1):

You could setup a guard clause with a return statement:

```
public void Method1(){

 bool isOK = false;

 if(!isOK) return; // <- guard clause

 // code here will not execute...


}
```