# how to stop the execution of current method call

Tags: c#

if a condition occurs i have to stop the execution of the current method call and return to the state before the method call .how can i do it .. suppose a i am executing some sample method and a condition occurs and i am prompting a message box and then i want to return to state before this function call

Comment: Does the executed method detect this condition or is it detected in some other thread?

Comment: What do you mean "return to the state before the method call"? revert all assignments?

Comment: This Question was asked in: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/744013/how-to-cancel-the-execution-of-a-method as well

Comment: It sounds like you're asking a few different questions here: 1. How to stop method execution; 2. How to revert the state of an object; Could you please clarify whether this is actually what you were asking, or whether you meant something different? Cheers.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can use the [Memento pattern](http://www.dofactory.com/Patterns/PatternMemento.aspx) to implement object rollback.  From [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memento_pattern) ...

> The caretaker is going to do something
>   to the originator, but wants to be
>   able to undo the change. The caretaker
>   first asks the originator for a
>   memento object. Then it does whatever
>   operation (or sequence of operations)
>   it was going to do. To roll back to
>   the state before the operations, it
>   returns the memento object to the
>   originator.

Once you receive the event that indicates that you should roll back, you can undo the change and return to the caller.  Here is some [info. and links](http://msmvps.com/blogs/peterritchie/archive/2007/08/22/thead-abort-is-a-sign-of-a-poorly-designed-program.aspx) on why you should not use Thread.Abort.

Comment: it worked but i am getting a message box thread was being aborted how to avoid that

Comment: i just want this happen with out the message box 
how to do it

Comment: Thread.Abort seems like overkill when you just want to stop the current method call. Just use a return statement.

Comment: Why is this the answer? It doesn't seem to answer the question - Thread.Abort will stop execution, but how does it return anything to its original state?

Comment: @JP, just edit this and turn it to a good answer, there is 40 rep in it for you ... Thread.Abort cures no problems, it only creates a big mess that is impossible to debug. async exceptions were invented by the devil. http://www.bluebytesoftware.com/blog/2009/03/13/ManagedCodeAndAsynchronousExceptionHardening.aspx

Comment: Thanks Sam! :)  I gave the original answer a while back (when I didn't really understand SO) -- it was intended to be tongue-in-cheek, but once it got accepted, I didn't know what to do.

Answer (score 5):

If I'm understanding you correctly, you wish to undo changes you have made to certain variables if some condition is true? If that's the case, you will want to store a copy of all your variables (or your class as a whole). Then, if your condition comes up true, you'll have to revert all those variables to their initial state before returning from your function. It would be something like this:

```
// In order to clone your variable, you may need to inherit from 
// ICloneable and implement the Clone function.
bool MyFunction(ICloneable c)
{
    // 1. Create a copy of your variable
    ICloneable clone = c.Clone();

    // 2. Do whatever you want in here
    ...

    // 3. Now check your condition
    if (condition)
    {
        // Copy all the attributes back across to c from your clone
        // (You'll have to write the ResetAttributes method yourself)
        c.ResetAttributes(clone);

        // Put a message box up
        MessageBox.Show("This failed!");

        // Now let the caller know that the function failed
        return false;
    }
    else
    {
        // Let the caller know that the function succeeded
        return true;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

A generic rollback functionality on the heap is for me unheard of. But you can use the Command pattern to get undo functionality and use it for rolling back:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Command_pattern

Essentially you encapsulate an operation in an object that stores enough information of the change that it can undo it. You push that object onto a stack, and when your condition occurs, you go pop all command objects from the stack and undo them. Without more information about your case it's difficult to give more specific information or tell whether this is applicable for you.

Answer (score 1):

Is it an error condition that could have been checked before calling the method? If so, throw an exception.

Otherwise, `return` something meaningful (e.g. if it's a `void` function, change it to return a `bool`, and return `false`).

Answer (score 1):

This is what exceptions are for. You throw an exception to terminate the function and any caller, until an exception handler is reached.

Note that this should only be done if something exceptional has occurred; exceptions shouldn't be used as a "different kind of" return value, as they are more costly in terms of code size (whether thrown or not) and running time (if thrown) , than normals returns.

As far as returning to the state you had before, this is possible *if* your code and any library code through which the call proceeded was written in an *exception safe* manner.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you are talking on the lines of object transactions OR transactional memory.

The least you can do is you can record the state (assignments) of the object being modified and write the old values on it when the condition to assignment fails.

Answer (score 0):

Another solution, differing slightly from those above:

Check for the specified condition a bit now and then in your sample method.

```
public void MyMethod()
{
some code

if (conditionOccurred == true){ reset to the previous state and exit;}

more code
}
```

This is probably not according to the book, but it gives quite simple and readable code if you don't use it too often.

I probably don't have to mention that you need save the program's state if you want to be able to return to it, and you need to write some code that returns you to this state.