# In what case execution of a .NET method can be interrupted by another one

Tags: c#, multithreading

In a **classic single thread winform application** I would like to know if a .NET method can be interrupted by another one.

I know that in some case like for example with the instruction Thread.Sleep(1000); or Application.DoEvents(); then a Timer_Tick can "take" the execution, but **is there another case where a method will be interrupted** ?

Also if the method is interrupted I would like to know when the execution will come back to the previous method ? At the end of the Timer_Tick ? (if Timer_Tick toke the execution)

Comment: It sounds like you need to _cancel_ a method, which is what Cancellation Tokens are for (but not required to use). You need to have another thread of your application changed a shared variable (like `bool stopRunning = true`), and your main method periodically checks that it should stop mid flight. There isn't a way to hijack you way into the method. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/744013/how-to-cancel-the-execution-of-a-method

Comment: no I absolutely don't want to cancel any method, and actually I would like all my method not being interrupted in any way but I don't know hows to do that as it appear that they are...

Comment: @fasa The answer is: **NO**. As I know. Except for a *kill process* or if *controlled by a debugger*.

Comment: so the ONLY way to interrupt a method is Thread.Sleep(1000); and Application.DoEvents(); ? Else it will NEVER be interrupted by any other in any case ?

Comment: @fasa Did you mean "interrupt/stop" or "suspend/pause" ?

Comment: `Thread.Sleep(1000);` doesn't "interrupt" a method any more than counting to 1 billion 1 billion times does. It just take a long time to execute that one line.

Comment: No I mean the method is suspended and Timer_Tick take the execution

Comment: You deleted your first question and re-posted it now with a little more information, but it's still unclear.  Why do you need all events to stop firing?  What's the real world problem you are trying to solve?  You might be going about this all wrong.

Comment: @fasa - That's not what happens.  Timer events are processed one of two ways, either as background threads, or as Windows Message Pump events.  The background just runs whenever it wants, it doesn't suspend anything.  The latter only runs if a method is called that runs the pump, such as DoEvents.

Comment: I saw that if I put a Application.DoEvents(); then the execution can go to Timer_Tick and I would like to know if there are other case were that happen... I'm not sure that it happen with Thread.Sleep(1000); ... Is it ?

Comment: Timer ticks won't be processed during `Thread.Sleep` if you use a WinForms timer.  Other types of timers will allow it.

Comment: @Olivier Rogier What ?! you mean the Timer_Tick can suspend the current execution thread, in the middle of a method even without any Application.DoEvents(); or Thread.Sleep(1000); ? ... That would be a bad news... And how can I prevent that please ?

Comment: Thanks a lot cHao for the information, very hard to get some info on all that ch.. things.

Comment: @fasa I talked about System.Threading.Timer, see answer for Forms Timer.

Comment: @fasa: It's easier to get info if you give info. A lot of what you want to know depends on your use case. And frankly, the fact that you're that worried about it hints to me that you might be looking for an answer to the wrong question. (Threads in any modern OS get suspended and resumed all the time as a matter of course, due to preemptive multitasking. If you're worried about threads messing with each other, you need to look into synchronization etc.)

Comment: @fasa - When you call DoEvents(), it runs the Windows Message Pump, and Messages are dispatched, in the case of WM_TIMER messages, these call your Timer_Tick function.  This is really no different from whether you have another method (say DoSomething()) that itself calls another method.  Nothing is suspended, it just goes off on another function call, and returns back afterwards.